# Why OpenCV is releasing "World.dll" in 2.4.7?

Tags: opencv

I heard OpenCV will have "world.dll", a single library that will have the combined functionality of all the other modules in the next release. My question is why would OpenCV do this now while in the past releases, it has always divided the functionality into categorized modules. Is there any special benefit for this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Some info here: http://www.programmerfish.com/should-you-be-using-opencv-world-module/

The main aspect is to make deployment of end-user applications easier - you only have one DLL file instead of many.

I guess there is also a slight performance increase in loading times, because loading one DLL means more continous reading from HDD.